how to get element when long pressed on flutter_markdown widget?
I would like to obtain the element at the location where a user long-pressed on the MarkdownBody of flutter_markdown, so that I can pop up a menu for the user to operate. My question is how to retrieve the element that has been long-pressed.

This should be possible by registering builders to your MarkdownWidget.
To give you a minimal example I will make some assumptions:

you have control over the markdown data
you want to show the menus only for specific elements
the target elements are inline and will look like some links
each element can have different menu items

For this, I will create a custom element, let's call it custom-element. This element has one attribute id which will allow us to display a diferent menu based on it:
[custom-element id='some-id']A custom element[/custom-element]

To support this custom element we create a CustomElementSyntax and a CustomElementBuilder. The CustomElementBuilder is responsible for creating the Widget for the custom element. For simplicity I create a Text widget. However it has to be wrapped in a GestureDetector in order to handle long presses. We wrap everything with a Builder because we will need the  BuildContext of the element in order to get the RenderBox that will help us determine the position of the menu.
Here is the complete code:
https://dartpad.dev/?id=4e52a8a9467ed12d7cc459965e77a592
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';
import 'package:markdown/markdown.dart' as md;

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: DemoPage(),
    )
  );
}

class DemoPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DemoPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: MarkdownBody(
            data:
                'This is a markdown widget with custom elements.\n\n[custom-element id="element-1"]Element 1[/custom-element]\n\n[custom-element id="element-2"]Element 2[/custom-element]',
            builders: <String, MarkdownElementBuilder>{
              'custom-element':
                  CustomElementBuilder(onLongPress: showMenuForCustomElement),
            },
            extensionSet: md.ExtensionSet(
              [],
              [CustomElementSyntax()],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> showMenuForCustomElement(
      BuildContext context, String id) async {
    final RenderBox? renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;

    if (renderBox == null) {
      return;
    }

    final Offset offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    // You can use renderBox.size to set a position offset to the menu
    final RelativeRect position = RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
      offset.dx,
      offset.dy + renderBox.size.height,
      offset.dx,
      offset.dy + renderBox.size.height,
    );

    print('Id: $id, position: $position');

    final List<PopupMenuEntry<String>> items = switch (id) {
      'element-1' => const [
          PopupMenuItem(
            value: 'action-1.1',
            child: Text('Action 1.1'),
          ),
          PopupMenuItem(
            value: 'action-1.2',
            child: Text('Action 1.2'),
          ),
        ],
      'element-2' => const [
          PopupMenuItem(
            value: 'action-2.1',
            child: Text('Action 2.1'),
          ),
          PopupMenuItem(
            value: 'action-2.2',
            child: Text('Action 2.2'),
          ),
          PopupMenuItem(
            value: 'action-2.3',
            child: Text('Action 2.3'),
          ),
        ],
      _ => [],
    };

    if (items.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }

    final selectedItem = await showMenu(
      context: context,
      position: position,
      items: items,
    );

    print('Selected item: $selectedItem');
  }
}

class CustomElementSyntax extends md.InlineSyntax {
  static const _pattern =
      r'^\[custom-element id="(.+)"\](.+)\[/custom-element\]$';

  CustomElementSyntax() : super(_pattern);

  @override
  bool onMatch(md.InlineParser parser, Match match) {
    final id = match[1]!;
    final text = match[2]!;

    final node = md.Element.text('custom-element', text);
    node.attributes['id'] = id;
    parser.addNode(node);

    return true;
  }
}

class CustomElementBuilder extends MarkdownElementBuilder {
  final void Function(BuildContext context, String id)? onLongPress;

  CustomElementBuilder({
    this.onLongPress,
  });

  @override
  Widget visitElementAfter(md.Element element, TextStyle? preferredStyle) {
    final String textContent = element.textContent;
    final String id = element.attributes['id'] ?? '';
    return Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onLongPress: () => onLongPress?.call(context, id),
          child: Text(textContent),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

